How to filter Data from 2 different sheets via Date
How can I count the Datas from different dates and different reasons for denial from one sheet to another sheet. Here's the information with the sheets

I used this code but won't work :
=COUNTIFS(Datas!C:C, "No Receipt", C:C, ">=11/03/2024", C:C, "<=11/05/2024")


I want to filter the numbers based on the reason of the denial from one google sheet to another for my report.

Try this Solution
My response is based on my understanding of counting the occurrences of "No Receipt" from the Datas Sheet to the Collectedf Sheet.
Formula used
Date Nov 3 - 5
=COUNTIFS(Datas!B2:B4, "No Receipt", Datas!A2:A4, ">=11/03/2023", Datas!A2:A4, "<=11/05/2023")

Date Nov 6 - 7
=COUNTIFS(Datas!B5:B6, "No Receipt", Datas!A5:A6, ">=11/06/2023", Datas!A5:A6, "<=11/07/2023")

Date Nov 8 - 9
=COUNTIFS(Datas!B7:B8, "No Receipt", Datas!A7:A8, ">=11/08/2023", Datas!A7:A8, "<=11/09/2023")

Date Nov 10 - 13
=COUNTIFS(Datas!B9:B12, "No Receipt", Datas!A9:A12, ">=11/10/2023", Datas!A9:A12, "<=11/13/2023")

Sample Output
Collectedf sheet

Datas sheet


It's weird the result on my end is 0

Can you share the exact code or result on your end so that I can explain or suggest what you need to change.
